# Recreate database view using migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, view

Is it possible to recreate a database view using a migration? Migration that was used to create a view on database is no more as per the changes done in some table structures. How do I recreate a view as per the new design? Do I have to drop the existing view and create a new through the migration? Or is there a simpler way without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a view stored in the database, the usual technique in Rails would be not to do that but use scopes in your ActiveModel instead.  This next statement is more with MySQL specifically in mind, but probably true generally:  as long as you have the indices properly set up, that approach should be as fast as having a view in the database itself and be more programmatically easy to work with.  You can specify calc'd fields in a scope through SQL statements if appropriate, though the usual response to that idea is why not have that be an accessor function in your model (as if it were in the database).

Does this help or am I answering a different question than you had?

Comment: View is union of 5 different select statements and now as per the new design some of the where conditions and calculated columns have changed. So, dropping the existing view and then creating a new updated view through a migration will not cause any data loss or will it?

Comment: If by loss of data, you mean what is actually stored as persistent data, then selects and calculations are not persistently stored and so  you won't suffer data loss.  Your indices are the critical element to manage.   First question you would ask yourself though is how to test this?  What is the test you'd run after the coding to confirm that all is well?  Do you have integration or other database tests that you can rewrite against your rails application to confirm that obvious cases are still running correctly?  The tests will not only help to confirm your new scopes but to show others.